# Flutter use class for JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to learn to flutter but notions are quite difficult for me.

I was working with local json files which I load at the start and then do calculations with the values ​​inside.

But I see everywhere that everyone uses class to parse JSON.

Classes are a fairly complex concept for me. I find it more complicated to handle.
In my example if I get a particular user and I want to add a KEY / VALUE to it, I can't do it if I go through a class. How to do ?

Is it useful to use class if I just load json files and retrieve values ​​inside to do statistics?

**My homeController.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:myapp/widgets/users.dart';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadJson() async {
  final myJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jsons/myjson.json');
  return {
    'myJson': myJson,
  };
}

class HomeController extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeController({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeControllerState createState() => _HomeControllerState();
}

class _HomeControllerState extends State<HomeController> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (() => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: loadJson(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return LinearProgressIndicator();
            }
            
            print('WITH CLASS =====================================');
            var myJson1 = jsonDecode(snapshot.data['myJson'])['user'] as List;
            List<User> myList1 = myJson1.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
            List selectedInList1 = myList1.where((e) => e.arg2>= 250).toList();
            User chooseObject1 = selectedInList1.first;
            chooseObject1.putIfAbsent('newKey', () => 'test'); // ???????????????????????
            print(chooseObject1);

            print('WITHOUT CLASS =====================================');
            var myJson = json.decode(snapshot.data['myJson']) ;
            List myList = myJson['user'];
            List selectedInList = myList.where((e) => e['arg2'] >= 250).toList();
            Map chooseObject = selectedInList.first;
            chooseObject['newKey'] = "test";
            print(chooseObject);

// Some code ...
```

**My json**

```
{
  "user" : [
    {
      "arg1"      : 1,
      "arg2"      : 200
    },
    {
      "arg1"      : 1,
      "arg2"      : 250
    },
    {
      "arg1"      : 1,
      "arg2"      : 300
    }
  ]
}
```

**My User Class**

```
class User{
  final int arg1;
  final int arg2;

  User(
    this.arg1,
    this.arg2
  );

  factory User.fromJson(dynamic json){
    return User(
      json['arg1'] as int,
      json['arg2'] as int
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.arg1}, ${this.arg2} }';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Studying a framework, library, engine, a new programming language, other technology (any abstraction) without knowing something that is required to know to be able to use it is more difficult and longer (a priori) task. It's like studying physics without some math knowledge. Of course, it doesn't mean that it's impossible. More than that many people are learning like that all the way. It's like not learning from bottom to top, but from top to bottom. It means that you want to make something, and to do it, you don't learn everything and then do it, but trying to do something, then learn the next things that a required to go closer to your goal. And everything is OK with that method. Everyone decides which method fits him better.

Everyone and everywhere use classes because classes in OOP languages (and Dart is an OOP language) are one of the base blocks using which we are creating our programs. More than that, I should mention, that all your program is written with classes. Classes are everywhere in Dart, practically everything is a class in Dart (if not everything literally).

You've said that you can't add a key/value to your class. You can't because you've not added such a behavior to your `User` class. `Map` is also just a class (that has been written for you by Dart creators). And it doesn't mean that you could not write something like that. You can just add a method (or operator overloading) to accomplish this task. It could be like that:

```
class User{
  // ...
  
  void add(String key, dynamic value) {
    // ... implementation
  }
}
```

And then you could do just the same.

Another open question is why do you really need to add a new key/value pair to your `User`? What problem that ability will help you to solve? Maybe you just declare this field in the `User` class? Or maybe you need to define another class? I couldn't answer this question, because I don't know what are you going to achieve.

So, I suppose the real question is: why should everyone prefer parse JSON data into custom classes instead of using a predefined `Map` class? There are many reasons to do that. First of all: it is to be able to reason about (and not only for humans but for a compilers either). What does `Map` class represents? It represents a collection of key and value pairs. No more no less. So there is no guarantee of what a particular collection contains? It could be empty, or it could contain something else or whatever. And working with such a collection is more difficult and error-prone (you are to remember everything by yourself, and the compiler will not help you). In our case, we could say that a map is raw data, i.e. a collection of unknown raw data. We do not really know what it is exactly until we'll check it. But when we define a class for our data we have not just a collection of raw data but a collection of `User` (a collection with known keys (data) and behavior (methods)). No more no less, with some guarantees. Like every object in that collection has a type of `User`. Every object has all fields that are declared in the `User` class. All of those fields have a specified type. It is very convenient. And now we not only know with what data we are working but the compiler either. And it will help us all the time. It will show type errors, it will generate more reliable and fast programs. And many other advantages. For example, when you access a property like that: `e['arg2']` a compiler doesn't know whether the `e` contains such a key or not. But when you access to property like that: `e.arg2` than the compiler 100% sure that such a key exists. Then, for example, let's imagine that we need to change a key name for some reason. In the first example, we can change it in one place and we can forget (easily) in every other place. So the program wouldn't work well in such a case. If we change a key name in the `User` class we wouldn't able to compile a program until we change *every* line of code with the old key name. It's also a huge difference. Of course, when you are writing a small program like that it's not a big deal to change it and to remember everything. But software complexity grows extremely fast and even in a medium program, it becomes a real problem. 20% of the time we are writing a program and 80% we are debugging it and fixing bugs. Classes allow us to greatly reduce the number of things that we should think about ourselves.

Of course, there are many other reasons (and it's difficult to put them all down in one answer), it's just a simple example to answer why. You can continue to write programs in a way that is convenient for you. It's OK. Some day, with some experience you will grasp the advantages of classes either. If you want to have some deeper know you are to read some OOP book and have some practice with it.